# The spaces between words in column names of a dataframe cause problem in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to display the summary and visualize the model of a regression by giving other variables as inputs every time. While the code works I changed the column names of the `iris` datasets by creating spaces between them and now I get error beacuse of this  `Error in parse: <text>:1:3: unexpected symbol`

```
     library(shiny)
        library(shinydashboard)
        library(shinydashboardPlus)
        library(shinyWidgets)
        library(dplyr)
        library(ggiraph)
        library(ggiraphExtra)
        library(plyr)
        shinyApp(
          ui = dashboardPagePlus(
            header = dashboardHeaderPlus(title = "Social Media Metrics", titleWidth = 320
                                         
            ),
            sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = 320,
                                       
                                       uiOutput("value"),
                                       uiOutput("value2")
                                       
            ),
            body = dashboardBody(
              verbatimTextOutput("plot"),
              ggiraphOutput("plot2"),
              plotOutput("plot3")
            )
            
            
          ),
          server = function(input, output) {
            
            colnames(iris)[1:4]<-c("f f","s s","d d","f f f")
            
            output$value<-renderUI({
              
              pickerInput(
                inputId = "val"
                ,
                label = "DEPENDENT" 
                ,
                choices = colnames(iris)[-5] #all rows of selected column
                ,
                multiple = F, options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
                
              )
              
              
            })
            output$value2<-renderUI({
              
              pickerInput(
                inputId = "val2"
                ,
                label = "INDEPENDENT" 
                ,
                choices = colnames(iris)[-5] #all rows of selected column
                ,
                multiple =T, options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
                
              )
            })
            
            
            
            model <- eventReactive(c(input$val,input$val2),{
              req(c(input$val,input$val2))
              lm(as.formula(paste(input$val," ~ ",paste(input$val2,collapse="+"))),data=iris)
            })
            
            output$plot <- renderPrint({
              summary(model())
            })
            output$plot2 <- renderggiraph({
              ggPredict(model(),se=TRUE,interactive=TRUE)
            })
            output$plot3<-renderPlot({
ggplot(iris,aes(y=input$val,x=input$val2))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method="lm")
})

            
            
            
          }
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use backticks to define the model variables if they contain spaces:

```
lm(as.formula(paste0("`",input$val,"` ~ ",paste0("`",input$val2,"`",collapse="+"))),data=iris)
```

This  makes the model work.
However, this doesn't work properly with `ggpredict` because the backticks aren't saved in the model itself:
[image]

Looking at source of `ggpredict` shows that it seems difficult to overcome this difficulty without modifying the code of the function, see for example line 15 which causes the error above :

```
temp = paste0("aes(y=", yname, ",x=", xname)
```

Comment: I added a ggplot version can this work?It looks like it gives always the same point

Comment: ggplot will work with [`aes_string`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/1.0.0/topics/aes_string) instead of `aes`

Comment: Good answer (+1). @firmo23 you should fill an issue on Github. As a workaround, you can rename the variables before running `lm`.